# How to get detailed info about conversions with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single target page on my site, the "Thank You for Signup" page.

I would like to answere simple questions about people who visited this page:

- For each access where it came from? AdWords (from wich campaign?), Organic Saerch (with wich search, Referral (from where?) or direct?

We have tried funels but it did not answere my questions.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use segments to achieve this. For example, if you want to list all traffic sources for your goals, you can do this:

1. Go to "Acquisition / All Traffic"
2. Click "+Add Segment" and give it a name
3. Click "Conditions" under "Advanced"
4. Setup your condition like this: [Goal Completions] [per session] [ > ] [0]
5. Unselect "All Sessions" segment to show only the rows matching your custom segment

When your segment is created, you can use it in any of Google Analytics tabs: Adwords, Organic Search, Referral, etc...